# Switching from wsconsume to wsimport changes namespace

Tags: java-8, jax-ws, java-11, porting, wsimport

I'm having problems with code generated from wdl while porting from Java 8 to Java 11.

Using maven 3.8.7 in both cases.

This is the `pom.xml` file that has been working with Java 1.8.0

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jboss.ws.plugins
  <artifactId>maven-jaxws-tools-plugin
  <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
  <configuration>
     <wsdls>
        <wsdl>some/dir/junk.wsdl</wsdl>
     </wsdls>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <goals>
           <goal>wsconsume</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here is the relevant snippet from the wdl that I'm using: `junk.wsdl`

```
<definitions targetNamespace = "URN:blah:blah:someClass:1.0"
```

I have no control over the wsdl as it is controlled by another entity. When I run `mvn clean package`, it creates a class named `someClass.java` which contains the line

```
 package  blah.blah.someClass._1_0;
```

When I do this with my updates for java 11 code (pom shown below), I do not get any errors, but the package name is missing the "_0"

```
 package  blah.blah.someClass._1;
```

Here is the `pom.xml` after I've updated it to use `wsimort` instead of `wsconsume`.

Java 11.0.20 pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
     <wsdlDirectory>some/dir</wsdlDirectory>
     <wsdlFiles>
        <wsdl>junk.wsdl</wsdl>
     </wsdlFiles>
     <extension>true</extension>
  </configuration>
    <executions>
     <execution>
        <goals>
           <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I have never completely wrapped my head around web services and such, but I strongly suspect that the _0 at the end of the namespace is important.
Meaning, I have not properly upgraded this portion of the code.

So, does that _0 matter, and if so, how to I get wsimport to preserve it?